# Problema recibiendo JSON: "A JSONObject text must begin with '{'"

Tags: java, json

La respuesta a mi petición me entrega este JSON:

```
"version": "1.6.0",
"autor": "mindicador.cl",
"fecha": "2019-11-13T12:00:00.000Z",
"uf": {

  "codigo": "uf",
  "nombre": "Unidad de fomento (UF)",
  "unidad_medida": "Pesos",
  "fecha": "2019-11-13T03:00:00.000Z",
  "valor": 28095.18

}
```

quiero sacar la uf pero me da el error

> A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: No es un JSON válido. Como te indica el error, debería empezar y terminar con llaves ( `{  }`). Más información en http://json.org/json-es.html

Comment: @LukasBustos Primero asegura modificar tu json, Agrega también como estas tratando de obtener el valor de "uf" , saludos

Comment: @Jorgesys JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://mindicador.cl/api");
        logger.debug(json);
esa es la manera que he intentado, pero me salta el error del titulo no puedo extraer lso datos